# Mysql statement not working with multiple AND clauses

Tags: sql, syntax-error, where-clause

So this sql is designed to return 1 random project from the projects table

```
$sql = "select title, id, user_id, priority from projects
where ( closed = 0 and priority between 7 and 9 AND  user_id=$user_id )
ORDER by rand(), priority
limit 1";
```

No matter how I rearrange them with parenthesis etc. the query returns invalid error like

```
Notice: Undefined variable: user_id in /var/www/html/producerswip/includes/functions.php on line 734

Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') ORDER by rand(), priority limit 1' at line 2 in /var/www/html/producerswip/includes/functions.php:737 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/html/producerswip/includes/functions.php(737): PDO->prepare('select title, i...') #1 /var/www/html/producerswip/index.php(72): getRandomProject() #2 {main} thrown in /var/www/html/producerswip/includes/functions.php on line 737
```

**UPDATE**
This is a total face palm moment. I was so focused on the sql statement error I ignored the first line which actually states the error. Thanks @David and others who have their eyes open. I have also taken @David advice and changed my sql to the following which is less attractive to sql injection

```
$sql = "select title, id, user_id, priority from projects
where ( closed = ? and priority between ? and ? AND user_id=? )
ORDER by rand(), priority
limit 1";
$results = $pdo->prepare($sql) or die(mysqli_error($pdo));
$results->execute([0,7,9,$user_id]);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Notice: Undefined variable", "Notice: Undefined index", and "Notice: Undefined offset" using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/notice-undefined-variable-notice-undefined-index-and-notice-undefined)

Comment: @JNevill and David I totally didnt see that first line. Face Palm. You're right of course, I just delete my question now, or wait till one of you post the answer and select it?

Comment: It's recommended that you also refer to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php  The root problem here is the SQL injection vulnerability.  You're not in control of the SQL syntax being executed.

Comment: @David I have updated my code, thanks for the reminder on using prepared statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your `$user_id` variable is not defined, meaning your resulting query would become the following:

```
where ( closed = 0 and priority between 7 and 9 AND  user_id= )
ORDER by rand(), priority
limit 1
```

Since there is no value after the `user_id=`, the query is invalid.